# I would like to mint a new token on solana. How can I do this using solana-web3.js?

Tags: javascript, solana

I'm using the `solana-web3.js` but can't find any examples for how to create and mint my own tokens. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this you'll also need to be using our token program js bindings. You can import them via npm as you can see in the sample code below.

```js
const web3 =  require('@solana/web3.js');
const splToken = require('@solana/spl-token');

(async () => {

    //create connection to devnet
    const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

    //generate keypair and airdrop 1000000000 Lamports (1 SOL)
    const myKeypair = web3.Keypair.generate();
    await connection.requestAirdrop(myKeypair.publicKey, 1000000000);

    console.log('solana public address: ' + myKeypair.publicKey.toBase58());

    //set timeout to account for airdrop finalization
    let mint;
    var myToken
    setTimeout(async function(){ 

        //create mint
        mint = await splToken.Token.createMint(connection, myKeypair, myKeypair.publicKey, null, 9, splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID)

        console.log('mint public address: ' + mint.publicKey.toBase58());

        //get the token accont of this solana address, if it does not exist, create it
        myToken = await mint.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
            myKeypair.publicKey
        )

        console.log('token public address: ' + myToken.address.toBase58());

        //minting 100 new tokens to the token address we just created
        await mint.mintTo(myToken.address, myKeypair.publicKey, [], 1000000000);

        console.log('done');

    }, 20000);

})();
```

Comment: Let's say I want users to come and mint tokens on my website. Do I need to create the keypair from javascript API only? Can't I create the wallet and fromAccount from CLI and use the creds in javascript code for minting and transferring tokens?

Comment: @chase-barker Where do you specify the specific NFT you are going for?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of how you can do that.
Assumptions:

1. You (mintRequester) have a Phantom wallet.
2. The minting will take place from a separate *minting wallet*, and not your Phantom wallet.
3. Some SOL is air-dropped into this newly created *minting wallet* to handle the minting charges.
4. Your new token has 6 decimal places and you are minting 1 token.
5. The token(s) are finally transferred from your *minting wallet* to your Phantom wallet.

**Code**

```js
import * as web3 from '@solana/web3.js';
import * as splToken from '@solana/spl-token';
 
 const getProvider = async () => {
    if ("solana" in window) {
      const provider = window.solana;
      if (provider.isPhantom) {
        console.log("Is Phantom installed?  ", provider.isPhantom);
        return provider;
      }
    } else {
      window.open("https://www.phantom.app/", "_blank");
    }
  };

const mintingTest = async () => {
    const phantomProvider = await getProvider();
    const mintRequester = await phantomProvider.publicKey;
    console.log("Public key of the mint Requester: ", mintRequester.toString());

    //To connect to the mainnet, write mainnet-beta instead of devnet
    const connection = new web3.Connection(
      web3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'),
      'confirmed',
    );

    //This fromWallet is your minting wallet, that will actually mint the tokens
    var fromWallet = web3.Keypair.generate();
     
    // Associate the mintRequester with this wallet's publicKey and privateKey
    // This is basically the credentials that the mintRequester (creator) would require whenever they want to mint some more tokens
   // Testing the parameters of the minting wallet
   
    console.log("Creator's Minting wallet public key: ",fromWallet.publicKey.toString());
    console.log(fromWallet.secretKey.toString());
    
    // Airdrop 1 SOL to the minting wallet to handle the minting charges
    var fromAirDropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
      fromWallet.publicKey,
      web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    );

    await connection.confirmTransaction(fromAirDropSignature);
    console.log("Airdropped (transferred) 1 SOL to the fromWallet to carry out minting operations");

    // This createMint function returns a Promise <Token>
    let mint = await splToken.Token.createMint(
      connection,
      fromWallet,
      fromWallet.publicKey,
      null,
      6, // Number of decimal places in your token
      splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    );

    // getting or creating (if doens't exist) the token address in the fromWallet address
    // fromTokenAccount is essentially the account *inside* the fromWallet that will be able to handle the              new token that we just minted
    let fromTokenAccount = await mint.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
      fromWallet.publicKey,
    );

    // getting or creating (if doens't exist) the token address in the toWallet address
    // toWallet is the creator: the og mintRequester
    // toTokenAmount is essentially the account *inside* the mintRequester's (creator's) wallet that will be able to handle the new token that we just minted
    let toTokenAccount = await mint.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
      mintRequester,
    );
    
    // // Minting 1 token
    await mint.mintTo(
      fromTokenAccount.address,
      fromWallet.publicKey,
      [],
      1000000 // 1 followed by decimals number of 0s // You'll ask the creator ki how many decimals he wants in his token. If he says 4, then 1 token will be represented as 10000
    );
    
    console.log("Initial mint successful");

    
    // This transaction is sending of the creator tokens(tokens you just created) from their minting wallet to their Phantom Wallet
    var transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
      splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction(
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        fromTokenAccount.address,
        toTokenAccount.address,
        fromWallet.publicKey,
        [],
        1000000, // This is transferring 1 token, not 1000000 tokens
      ),
    );
        
    var signature = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      transaction,
      [fromWallet],
      {commitment: 'confirmed'},
    );

    const creatorTokenAddress = mint.publicKey;
    const creatorTokenAddressString = mint.publicKey.toString();

    console.log("SIGNATURE: ", signature); //Signature is basically like the paying party signs a transaction with their key.
    console.log("Creator Token Address: ", creatorTokenAddressString);
    console.log("Creator Minting Wallet Address: ", mint.payer.publicKey.toString());
    
    let creatorTokenBalance = await toTokenAccount.amount;
    console.log("Creator's Token Balance: ", creatorTokenBalance);
  };
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much!

Comment: for step 2, i don't understand, you already have a wallet, why not just use the phantom wallet, instread of creating a new one?