# Call Solana web3.js from HTML

Tags: web3js, solana, solana-cli

I am trying to run web3.js from HTML. Now so far I have been able to call `window.solana.connect();` and `window.solana.disconnect();` functions. However when I try run below code it doesn't work. I have tested it various options, like removing "web3." from the code but still didn't work. I would apprecaite if someone can guide me on how I can establish the connection.

```
const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
```

Majority of my codes below is from the research done on Stackoveflow. Links below:
[Solana : Adding Sollet / Phantom Wallet Connect to my website - Steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68989348/solana-adding-sollet-phantom-wallet-connect-to-my-website-steps/69658348#69658348)
[I would like to mint a new token on solana. How can I do this using solana-web3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68215033/i-would-like-to-mint-a-new-token-on-solana-how-can-i-do-this-using-solana-web3/69050429#69050429)
[How can you transfer SOL using the web3.js sdk for Solana?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68166964/how-can-you-transfer-sol-using-the-web3-js-sdk-for-solana/69050522#69050522)
[How to properly transfer Solana SOL using web3js via Phantom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69546971/how-to-properly-transfer-solana-sol-using-web3js-via-phantom/69657075#69657075)

Unfortunately docs on Phantom website don't help either.  https://docs.phantom.app/integrating/establishing-a-connection

My existing codes below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to Decentralized Ecommerce</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/3.0.0-rc.5/web3.min.js" integrity="sha512-jRzb6jM5wynT5UHyMW2+SD+yLsYPEU5uftImpzOcVTdu1J7VsynVmiuFTsitsoL5PJVQi+OtWbrpWq/I+kkF4Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@latest/lib/index.iife.js"></script>

    <script src="/static/solana.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        async function transferSOL() {
            //Changes are only here, in the beginning
            if (window.solana.isConnected === false){
                const resp = await window.solana.connect();
            }
            const pubKey = await window.solana.publicKey;
            console.log("Public Key: ", pubKey);             

            // Establishing connection
            const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
            alert('hello2');

            // I have hardcoded my secondary wallet address here. You can take this address either from user input or your DB or wherever
            var recieverWallet = new web3.PublicKey("4iSD5Q6AnyhRHu6Uz4u1KAzXh3TwNwwQshEGhZbEXUTw");
            alert('hello3');

            // Airdrop some SOL to the sender's wallet, so that it can handle the txn fee
            var airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
                provider.publicKey,
                web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
            );

            // Confirming that the airdrop went through
            await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);
            console.log("Airdropped");

            var transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
                web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
                fromPubkey: provider.publicKey,
                toPubkey: recieverWallet,
                lamports: web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL //Investing 1 SOL. Remember 1 Lamport = 10^-9 SOL.
                }),
            );

            // Setting the variables for the transaction
            transaction.feePayer = await provider.publicKey;
            let blockhashObj = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
            transaction.recentBlockhash = await blockhashObj.blockhash;

            // Transaction constructor initialized successfully
            if(transaction) {
                console.log("Txn created successfully");
            }
            
            // Request creator to sign the transaction (allow the transaction)
            let signed = await provider.signTransaction(transaction);
            // The signature is generated
            let signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signed.serialize());
            // Confirm whether the transaction went through or not
            await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);

            //Signature or the txn hash
            console.log("Signature: ", signature);

            }
            
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Related question. I see 'Airdropped'. Does your source code arrange for an airdrop? I've asked how to do this task [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70751427/105539) and could use some advice.

Comment: Airdrop is for Solana on Devnet. This is only to test the codes etc.
Unfortunately, these codes won't work for airdrop of custom token. Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After importing the script on the HTML:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@latest/lib/index.iife.js"> </script>
```

You should be able to call:

```
const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
```

Note it is **solanaWeb3** not **web3**

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example with Solana Web3 1.4:

```js
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
```

Make sure to have installed the library via, `npm install @solana/web3.js`.